Is there a function or way in excel to dynamically take 6 values from ONE cell and compare it with another and return all the matches between the 6?
Let's say COLUMN A cell  A1 has values       AB111  CD000 EF222 GH333 LM555 RS444
AND lets say COLUMN B1 has some or all the same values in this case 3 matches    AB111 OP888 GH333 RS444 ZD999
I am trying to find any excel formula but needs to be dynamic to return the multiple matches between cell A1 AND Cell B1 because I'm doing this for 10,000 cells or maybe more.
have been struggling on this for a almost a week, any help would be greatly appreciated.
I want to return the matches from cell a1 and b1 into cell c1
I tried Concating the answers but it keeps getting big like an essay so I scratched that because it didn't seem to work and now I may be trying an IF and statement.  If only there was a formula that would check the whole contents of a cell because my matches would concat if they were exactly in order but due to the matches being in all different orders I need something else as this would not be dynamic and manually take to much time to fix.  Thanks for trying and any help!

You can use REDUCE:
=REDUCE(,TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),LAMBDA(a,c,a&IF(ISERR(FIND(c,B1)),," "&c)))


Another solution:
=LET(c,TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),TEXTJOIN(" ",,IF(ISERR(FIND(c,B1)),"",c)))


